# how to expire session WordPress

Tags: wordpress, session-timeout

I want that the user should automatically logout after time set - for example after 300 seconds if a user remains inactive, it should log out.  Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-sign-out-for-inactivity/

Not enough data to see if it is still compatible, but it should still work fine.

Comment: how to set the time i install it but i cant see any where this plugin?

Comment: It tells you how on the FAQ of the plugin page: http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-sign-out-for-inactivity/faq/